# Problem to load series data after fetch api using react/redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

**Problem**

Hello friends,

I'm developing an app with react + redux, the problem I have is that the series property that comes from

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     series: state.serieReducer
   }
}
```

It is showing me undefined in console, but if you see the image in the action it loads the 30 data in the array.

I would like if you could help me to solve the problem and be able to load the data in the render(){} function.

[image]

**src/components/Home/index.js**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Page from './page.js';
import fetchSeriesAction from '../../redux/actions/series/action.fetch.js';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'


class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSeries();
  }

  render(){

    console.log('TESTING SERIES LIST:', this.props) // show undefined

    return(
      <Page/>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return{
    series: state.serieReducer
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  fetchSeries: fetchSeriesAction
}, dispatch)


export default connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

## src/redux/actions/series

**serie/action.error.js**

```js
import {FETCH_SERIES_ERROR} from '../../types.js';

const fetchSeriesError = (error) =>{
  return {
    type: FETCH_SERIES_ERROR,
    error: error
  }
}


export default fetchSeriesError;
```

**series/action.pending.js**

```js
import {FETCH_SERIES_PENDING} from '../../types.js';

const fetchSeriesPending = () =>{
  return {
    type: FETCH_SERIES_PENDING
  }
}

export default fetchSeriesPending;
```

**series/action.success.js**

```js
import {FETCH_SERIES_SUCCESS} from '../../types.js';

const fetchSeriesSuccess = (series) =>{
  return {
    type: FETCH_SERIES_SUCCESS,
    series: series
  }
}

export default fetchSeriesSuccess;
```

**series/action.fetch.js**

```js
import fetchSeriesPending from './action.pending.js';
import fetchSeriesSuccess from './action.sucess.js';
import fetchSeriesError from './action.error.js';


const fetchData = () =>{
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchSeriesPending());
    await fetch('https://cinemanight.chrismichael.now.sh/api/v1/series/1')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if(res.error) {
            throw(res.error);
        }
        dispatch(fetchSeriesSuccess(res.series));
        return res.series;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(fetchSeriesError(error));
      })
  }
}

export default fetchData;
```

## reducers/series

**series/result.js**

```js
import { 
  FETCH_SERIES_ERROR,
  FETCH_SERIES_PENDING,
  FETCH_SERIES_SUCCESS
} from '../../types.js';

const defaultState = {
  pending: true,
  series: [],
  error: null
}

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) =>{
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_SERIES_PENDING:
      return{
        ... state,
        pending: true
      }
    case FETCH_SERIES_SUCCESS:
      return{
        ... state,
        pending: false,
        series: action.payload
      }
    case FETCH_SERIES_ERROR:
      return{
        ... state,
        pending: false,
        error: action.error
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

**series/index.js**

```js
import resultReducer from './result.js';

export default {
  resultReducer
}
```

## store.js

```js
import {createStore , combineReducers , applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import SeriesReducer from './reducers/series/index.js';

const middlewares  = [thunk , logger];

const reducers = combineReducers({
  ... SeriesReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducers , applyMiddleware(... middlewares));

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix either action.success.js or your reducer because in reducer you are setting `action.payload` and you are sending `series` from your action.success.js

Either change your action.success.js to:

```
import {FETCH_SERIES_SUCCESS} from '../../types.js';

const fetchSeriesSuccess = (series) =>{
  return {
    type: FETCH_SERIES_SUCCESS,
    payload: series
  }
}

export default fetchSeriesSuccess;
```

or change your reducer like this:

```
import { 
  FETCH_SERIES_ERROR,
  FETCH_SERIES_PENDING,
  FETCH_SERIES_SUCCESS
} from '../../types.js';

const defaultState = {
  pending: true,
  series: [],
  error: null
}

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) =>{
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_SERIES_PENDING:
      return{
        ... state,
        pending: true
      }
    case FETCH_SERIES_SUCCESS:
      return{
        ... state,
        pending: false,
        series: action.series
      }
    case FETCH_SERIES_ERROR:
      return{
        ... state,
        pending: false,
        error: action.error
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

update your mapStateToProps method as well:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     series: state.resultReducer
   }
}
```

Comment: now in the devtool in the next state part it shows me series: (30) [{}, {} ...], but the console.log ('TESTING SERIES LIST:', this.props) of the render shows me undefined in series

Comment: Even the resultReducer now has the correct values
resultReducer: {error: null, pending: false, series: (30) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, { …}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} , {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]}

But doing console log of this.props.series shows me undefined.

Comment: you need to fix your mapStatToProps method as well

Comment: @ChrisMichael I edited my comment. Please look into it

Comment: Waoo I see, I call the reducer in the mapStateToProp incorrectly.